# How can I initialize this strange array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization

How to initialize this rectangular array of ragged arrays?

```
int[,][] = 
{
    // something
}
```

Comment: In which language?

Comment: which language ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. I changed the title.

Comment: @derloopkat, no, `int[,][]` and `int[,,]` are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as Mohamed with different variables so you can see the results better :

```
            int[,][] abc = 
            {
                {new int[]{100,101,102}, new int[]{110,111,112}},
                {new int[]{200,201,202}, new int[]{210,211,212}}
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an 2 dimensional **array** of **arrays**. So you should initialize them like this:

```
int[,][] inputs = new int[,][]
{
    { new int[]{ 1, 2 }, new int[]{ 3, 4 }, new int[]{ 5, 6 }, new int[]{ 7, 8 } },
    { new int[]{ 1, 2 }, new int[]{ 3, 4 }, new int[]{ 5, 6 }, new int[]{ 7, 8 } }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be an example...

```
int[,][] x = new int[1, 1][];
x[0, 0] = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out.

```
int [,][] arr = 
{
    {
        new int[] {1,3,5},
        new int[] {4,6}
    },
    {
        new int[] {1},
        new int[] {0,0,0,0,0}
    },
    {
        new int[] {6,6,6,6},
        new int[] {1,2,3,4}
    }
}
```